# Fatal error - Media module

Tags: 7, views, media

I keep getting the following error for some reason:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare media_views_invalidate_cache() (previously declared in /var/www/html/sitename/sites/all/modules/media/media.views.inc:140) in /var/www/html/sitename/profiles/dkan/modules/contrib/media/media.views.inc on line 140

Is there any reason I'm getting the error?

I'm using Drupal 7.54.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have media installed twice. Once as part of your installation profile (or distribution) and once as a 'loose' module. Which I suppose occurred because there was a security update and you did not want to wait for the distribution to update.

Make a backup and remove `/sites/all/modules/media`. That should solve it.

Comment: Well I did that, however, it shows the following error message: User warning: The following module has moved within the file system: media. In order to fix this, clear caches or put the module back in its original location. For more information, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /var/www/html/sitename/includes/bootstrap.inc).  I also did a drush rr and it crashed the system and just a regular clean cache and it also crashes the system.

Comment: And what if you disable or uninstall it first? You'll need to get rid of the 2nd installation somehow